# Best way to plot categorical data

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a list like this:

```
 gender = ['male','female','male','female']
```

What would be the simplest way to plot the count of this list as a bar plot using matplotlib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter()` you can easily count the frequency of elements in your list.

Then you can create a [bar plot](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) using the code below:

```
gender = ['male','male','female','male','female']

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(gender)

men = c['male']
women = c['female']

bar_heights = (men, women)
x = (1, 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
width = 0.4

ax.bar(x, bar_heights, width)

ax.set_xlim((0, 3))
ax.set_ylim((0, max(men, women)*1.1))

ax.set_xticks([i+width/2 for i in x])
ax.set_xticklabels(['male', 'female'])

plt.show()
```

Resulting chart:

[image]

Comment: what if you want the category to appear on the y-axis?

Comment: @FC84 For horizontal bar plots, [check this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html).

Comment: @FC84 Also check `orientation='horizontal'` [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).

Answer (score 1):

```
uValues = list( set( gender))
xVals = range( 0, len( uValues))
yVals = map( lambda x: gender.count( uValues[x]), xVals)

import pylab
pylab.bar( xVals, yVals)
```

of course you won't have text on x-ticks, but the plot will be correct